# What does "depends nonlinearly" mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

A PDE is *fully nonlinear, if PDE depends nonlinearly on the highest order derivatives*.

What does nonlinear dependence mean here?

Comment: @Lovsovs So nonlinearly dependent means that it's a summation (or combination), but where some of the terms are nonlinear (cannot be written as a sum of linear terms)?

Comment: Go to [this site](https://www.myphysicslab.com/explain/classify-diff-eq-en.html) and search for "linear" (ctrl+f) (about halfway down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the PDE be $a-$th order, meaning that the highest (possibly mixed) derivative in the equation is order $a.$  We could write this PDE as $F(D^a u, D^{a-1} u, \dots , u(x) , x) = 0.$  If $F$ is nonlinear in any of the terms with an $a-$th order derivative (such as $\bigg(\frac{\partial^a u}{\partial x_1^a} \bigg)^2),$ then we say $F$ is a fully nonlinear PDE.  Note that here, $D^a u = \sum \frac{\partial^a}{\partial x_1^{a_1} \partial x_2^{a_2} \cdots \partial x_n^{a_n} }u(x)$ where $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = a$ and the sum is over all possible ways this is true.  Its called multi-index notation.

If you'd like a concrete example (like a second order equation), just ask in a comment.